# removeEventListener is necessary on document?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was wondering, creating an `addEventListener` with this function, is it necessary and possible remove in it with `removeEventListener`?

```
getFavTable = () => {
 document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', () => {
  if (document.querySelector('#todayfavtable') != null) {
    document.querySelector('#todayfavtable').scrollIntoView();
    window.scrollBy(0, -50);
    document.querySelector('#todayfavtable').offsetTop });
  } else {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: To remove this function, you have to declare it first and not as an anonymous one and send it at addEventListener and send it to removeEventListener when you need it

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to remove it in case you want it to last the entire time the user is on that page, but if you want to disable this, you would have to save a reference to that callback function, that way you will be able to use `removeEventListener` correctly.